# Scala's type definition like method call

Tags: scala

I am looking into spray-json example, and the last line `val color = json.convertTo[Color]` has a function call that gets class type specified? Almost looks like assigning type definition to a constant. Can somebody explain what is going on there in that context?

```
case class Color(name: String, red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int)
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val colorFormat = jsonFormat4(Color)
}

import MyJsonProtocol._
import spray.json._

val json = Color("CadetBlue", 95, 158, 160).toJson
val color = json.convertTo[Color]
```

Thanks

Comment: Does https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html address  the confusion for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what exactly it not clear to you. The type of your `json` variable is `JsValue`. That class has a generic `convertTo` method specified as

```
def convertTo[T :JsonReader]: T = jsonReader[T].read(this)
```

This code means that `convertTo` can be called for any type `T` for which there is an implicit object of type `JsonReader[T]` visible in the context. So this with some compiler magic is effectively the same code as

```
  def convertTo[T](implicit jsonReader: JsonReader[T]): T = jsonReader.read(this)
```

So what this trick is all about? Consider that you are the author of the Spray JSON library. Obviously there are many types that can not be reasonable decoded from JSON (for example, what exactly does it mean to decode `Thread`?). So you want your `JsValue.convertTo` method to be a "type safe" in the sense that you only allow decoding the types that at least might be theoretically decoded. Unfortunately, deciding this 100% automatically is a rather hard task. Still Spray JSON (as well as many other Scala JSON libraries) provide some approximation to that. The idea is that you declare a [type class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) `JsonReader[T]` that encodes exactly this property - type `T` can be decoded from JSON. Then you require that you decode only to those types that are members of the type class. This type class idea in Scala is typically implemented using [implicits](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html) i.e. you don't force the evidence to be passed explicitly but relies onto the compiler to find the evidence. Althoug often compiler can infer proper generic type substitutions just by the context, in this particular case there is no context and so you have to specify the type explicitly.

Note that line

```
implicit val colorFormat = jsonFormat4(Color)
```

uses another powerful Scala trick: macro. Spray JSON provide a macro library that will generate type class evidence for many types automatically.